# How can I combine free where filter in Elasticsearch JAVA version?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am deploying a new project with Elastic with elasticsearch-rest-client version 7.

Currently I work with SQL and I have a free filter in which the user writes the free query,
for example **(field1=24 OR field1 = 22 ) AND (field3 IS NULL OR field3 != 2)**.

And adding this part to the final query in SQL ORACLE is easy as long as there is no syntax error, but now in the Elasticsearch JAVA library I don't know how to transform said filter into a search with BoolQueryBuilder or any other constructor, I also have to add that must be combined with other BoolQueryBuilder filters.

could I put a series of filters with BoolQueryBuilder + free conditional where?

Any help is appreciated, even if it's just an approximation.
Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that query maybe be this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "num1": {
                    "value": 22
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "num1": {
                    "value": 24
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "exists": {"field": "num3"}
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "num3": {
                    "value": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```